# How to fix "invalid expression, current token ... not ended properly" error?

Tags: json, jasper-reports

This is my data

```
{
  "errorCode": null,
  "errorMessage": null,
  "responseItems": [
    {
      "personFirstName": "t16239d",
      "personLastName": "submitter 1",
      "hireDate": "20161106",
      "terminationDate": null,
      "startMonthYear": "01_2017",
      "endMonthYear": "12_2017",
      "staffTimeOffAllowances": [
        {
          "officeCode": null,
          "startMonthYear": null,
          "endMonthYear": null,
          "personId": null,
          "personCode": null,
          "allowancesIntotal": 10,
          "allowancesUsed": 0,
          "allowancesSubmitted": 0,
          "allowancesApproved": 0,
          "allowancesRemaining": 10,
          "timeOffType": {
            "id": 1284,
            "continent": "EU",
            "alphaId": "CA",
            "code": "SUM1",
            "description": "summer friday1",
            "account": "ADMIN1",
            "colourCode": "#CCCCCC",
            "visibility": "R",
            "approvalRequired": true,
            "commentRequired": false,
            "paid": true
          },
          "timeOffTypeWithoutAllowance": false,
          "proRataAllowanceData": false
        },
        {
          "officeCode": null,
          "startMonthYear": null,
          "endMonthYear": null,
          "personId": null,
          "personCode": null,
          "allowancesIntotal": 0,
          "allowancesUsed": 3,
          "allowancesSubmitted": 0,
          "allowancesApproved": 0,
          "allowancesRemaining": 3,
          "timeOffType": {
            "id": 1342,
            "continent": "EU",
            "alphaId": "CA",
            "code": "SICK",
            "description": "Sickness",
            "account": "SICK",
            "colourCode": "#CCCCCC",
            "visibility": "R",
            "approvalRequired": true,
            "commentRequired": false,
            "paid": true
          },
          "timeOffTypeWithoutAllowance": true,
          "proRataAllowanceData": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to extract the value of the `allowancesUsed` field of the first `staffTimeOffAllowances` entry that has `timeOffTypeWithoutAllowance = true`.

Mu current attempt is:

```
staffTimeOffAllowances[?(@.timeOffTypeWithoutAllowance==true)].allowancesUsed[0]
```

It compiles fine but then when I try to preview it, it fails with

> invalid expression, current token staffTimeOffAlowances[?(@ not ended properly

I tried a lot of variations of the same expression but no joy. Could someone please tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic [`json`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jsondatasource/index.html) query language needs absolute expressions. I would suggest stopping your query one level above your desired JSON property so that you can use it as the field expression(working with "leaf" values requires a special field expression - `"."` - and may produce unpredictable results). Having said that, you should be fine with this query and field mapping:

```
<queryString language="json">
    <![CDATA[responseItems.staffTimeOffAllowances(timeOffTypeWithoutAllowance == true)[0]]]>
</queryString>
<field name="allowancesUsed" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
```

Starting with JasperReports 6.3.1 you could use the more flexible/advanced [`jsonql`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jsonqldatasource/index.html) language. Just replace the above queryString declaration with either:

- This one:

  ```
  <queryString language="jsonql">
      <![CDATA[..staffTimeOffAllowances.*(timeOffTypeWithoutAllowance == true)[0]]]>
  </queryString>
  ```

  This query translates to: "get the `staffTimeOffAllowances` property from anywhere, get its children that have `timeOffTypeWithoutAllowance`, select the first one"
- or this one:

  ```
  <queryString language="jsonql">
      <![CDATA[..timeOffTypeWithoutAllowance(@val == true)^[0]]]>
  </queryString>
  ```

  This query translates to: "get the `timeOffTypeWithoutAllowance` property with a *true* value from anywhere, get its parents, select the first one"

**Important note**: [`json`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jsondatasource/index.html) and [`jsonql`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jsonqldatasource/index.html) are custom query languages unrelated to JsonPath, in spite of some resemblances. [`json`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jsondatasource/index.html) is the first(and very simplistic) attempt at providing a way to query JSON structures, followed by [`jsonql`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jsonqldatasource/index.html) which is meant to replace [`json`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jsondatasource/index.html) as it offers more capabilities and is more predictable.

Comment: Thank you very much! I must confess I had no idea abaout jsonql. My template was set to JSON and this field was just one flag I needed. I ended up changing the language (and my datasource classes) to jsonql and this works great. We will do more work with JSON on other templates so these tips are going to be invaluable - thanks again.